# How to declare Grand Central Dispatch

Tags: iphone, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I am using a pretty decent tutotial I have found for GCD, in it it shows you how to declare a new dispatch queue.

> Grand Central Dispatch operates using queues. Queues are a C typedef:
>   dispatch_queue_t. To get a new global queue, we call
>   dispatch_get_global_queue(), which takes two arguments: a long for
>   priority and an unsigned long for options, which is unused, so we’ll
>   pass 0ul. Here’s how we get a high-priority queue:

In it it says to pass 0ul in as a parameter like so

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
```

Im hoping someone can explain to me what 0ul is? and why its included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just 0 and the ul is telling the compiler that you want it to be an unsigned long to match the function signature.

dispatch_queue_t dispatch_get_global_queue(long priority, unsigned long flags);

If you don't add the ul the 0 will get treated as in integer which may cause a compiler warning.

Please look at the documentation here.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Comment: ah right, as so thats setting the markers (for lack of a better word) for the objects that will be in the queue.. it doesn't have anything to do with the data type that I want to multi thread etc.?

Comment: It has no effect at all, if you look at the documentation you will see it is an unused parameter hence 0.

Comment: cool, thanks for the reply got it working.. I feel like this should be more complicated (being multi threading) but its not! so weird!

Comment: The complicated part is making it not randomly crash/hang/lose data, not getting it working in the first place. Threading (at least outside the trivial cases) is still plenty hard.